# Ansible: unable to enter variable at prompt

Tags: ansible

I want to set a variable to some value defined by the user prompt. I can see that the prompt appears, the default value is set, but I'm not able to type anything at the prompt.

```
- hosts: web.servers
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "deployments"
      prompt: Enter remote deployments folder
      default: "/home/centos/tomcat/deploy"
```

Output:

```
Enter remote deployments folder [/home/centos/tomcat/deploy]:
```

I'm only able to hit <kbd>return</kbd> and assign the default value. Is there any issue with using path expressions with variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in fact type and enter the variable value, it's just not echoed to the screen.

Add `private: no` to the prompt definition (the default value is to hide user's input):

```
- hosts: web.servers
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "deployments"
      prompt: Enter remote deployments folder
      default: "/home/centos/tomcat/deploy"
      private: no
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!